# Joint PDF and Covariance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, covariance

$X$ is a standard normal random variable and $Y$ is a random variable which takes only the values of either 1 or -1, and $\Bbb E[Y]=1$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent. What is the distribution of $Z=XY$ and what is the covariance of $X$ and $Z$?

Here is what I have:
$$Y =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{with probability $p$} \\
-1, & \text{with probability $1-p$}
\end{cases}$$
$$Z=XY=\begin{cases}
X,  & \text{with probability $p$} \\
-X, & \text{with probability $1-p$}
\end{cases}$$
So therefore if $\text {Cov}(X,Z)=\Bbb E[XZ]=\Bbb E[X]\Bbb E[Z]$ we need $\Bbb E[XZ]$. Clearly $\Bbb E[X]\Bbb E[Z]$ must be zero because $X$ is standard normal. I also take $\Bbb E[Z]=\Bbb E[X]\Bbb E[Y]=0$ due to independence. So what is $\Bbb E[XZ]$?

I attempted to find the distribution of $XZ$ and got
$$Z=XY=\begin{cases}
X^2,  & \text{with probability $p$} \\
-X^2, & \text{with probability $1-p$}
\end{cases}$$
Is this right? If so, how can we get the expected value? If not, where am I going wrong?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(Y)=p\cdot 1+(1-p)(-1)=2p-1\neq 1$ unless $p=1$ in which case $Y=1$ almost surely—i.e. is constant... So something is inconsistent here with your problem’s setup.

Comment: The problem does not give the distribution of $Y$, only that it only can only take two values, 1 and -1. Is my distribution inaccurate?

Comment: If $EY=1$ and $Y$ takes on the values $\pm1$ only, then $Y=1$ with probability $1$, and $X=Z$ with probability $1$ and $Z\sim N(0,1)$.